# Deploy to a specific application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-api

I have an application on GitHub and I am working on making an interface to easily deploy branches of the application to separate Heroku applications for various reasons. Is it possible to specify a specific Heroku application you'd like to deploy a specific branch to using a Heroku deploy button?

Comment: "for various reasons" - heroku has stuff like this built-in, you know that? it supports pull-request-apps, i think there is not much more you would want other than that.

Answer (score 1):

If you have git and heroku toolbelt installed with your application, you could easily automate it by calling in in your shell

```
git push [your-heroku-app-as-a-remote] [branch_name]:master
```

Where [your-heroku-app-as-a-remote] could be a variable containing the heroku-app you need to push, and [branch_name] a var holding the branch name you want to push.

You could always automate the fetch of all remotes/branches and also the process of creating Heroku apps on the fly. Of course, any scripting language could be used to call all these actions with ease